# get value by name of a websocket response(string)

Tags: java, android, websocket

How to get the value by name of a websocket response(string),I have tried convert response into jsonArray but it didn't work.
So how can I get the value(mop floor) by key(task)? I am using android studio to develop app. The problem occurs at output ("Task to do: " +text.get("task"));

```
private final class EchoWebsocketListener extends WebSocketListener{
    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, okhttp3.Response response) {
        webSocket.send("{\n" +
                "   \"task\": \"Mop floor\",\n" +
                "   \"time_limit\": \"1\"\n" +
                "}");

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        output("Task to do: " +text.get("task"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        webSocket.close(1000,"Goodbye!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, okhttp3.Response response) {
        output("Error in websocket : " + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: you resolved this issue?